# Will ASP.Net MVC's AntiForgeryToken Method work with Load Balancers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, cookies, load-balancing, antiforgerytoken

Using ASP.Net MVC v2.0, I am starting to research the use of the `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` method when submitting forms that process data. I can see it sets a hidden value in the form HTML and it sets the same value in a session cookie.

The question is **will different web servers in a load balanced configuration create the same token in the HTML forms?** It seems if they don't then the cookie and hidden form value wouldn't match and we would have a problem. Before I get into actually testing this in a LB configuration, wanted to check if anyone already has experience with this?

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If all machines across the farm share the same `<machineKey>`, everything will work.  There are [lots of resources](http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=machine+key+web+farm) on how to set this.  There's also [a tutorial on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755177(WS.10).aspx).

Note that the name `<machineKey>` is a bit misleading, since this is actually set per-application in `~/Web.config`.  So set the `<machineKey>` explicitly in your app's Web.config, then deploy across your farm.

Comment: OK, I should have assumed the machineKey was used. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: And if your lazy to create a machinekey line for your config file: http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

Comment: nashwan, it's dangerous to use a machineKey that you didn't generate yourself. It could end up compromising the security of your site.

Comment: we generated machine key and added in web.config file. This issue occurred in one server scenario also